# How to install/run a watch task in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, watch

I'd like to run a given task, every time a file in the folder `src` changes.

It seems that Gradle does not have a task like that, but there is the [gradle-watch-plugin](https://github.com/bluepapa32/gradle-watch-plugin) on github. Following the installation guide, I tried:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bluepapa32:gradle-watch-plugin:0.1.5'
    }
}   

apply plugin: 'com.bluepapa32.watch'

task "sometask" << {
  println "My Own task."
}


watch {
    somename {
        files files('src')
        tasks 'sometask'
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this results in an error:

```
Starting:watch FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':watch'.
> org.gradle.tooling.BuildLauncher.withArguments([Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/gradle/tooling/BuildLauncher;
```

So what's wrong with my `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done without a plugin by enabling [continuous mode](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:continuous_build) in your build via the `--continuous` or `-t` command line argument. For example, given the following build script running `gradle -t myTask` will automatically watch for changes in the folder *src* and reexecute the task when those files change.

```
task myTask {
  inputs.files 'src'
  doLast {
    // do some stuff with files in 'src' folder
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a nice article in the Gradle blog: http://gradle.org/blog/feature-spotlight-continuous-build/. I found it when searching for your error message: https://github.com/bluepapa32/gradle-watch-plugin/issues/25